# PHP sort complex multidimensional array

Tags: php

I've been struggling trying to sort this array in PHP by "user_likes" and "created_time" I've looked at a few example on Stackoverflow but can't figure out the correct syntax. I want the order to go from the most "user_likes" and then "created_time" not sure if it's even possible. I've been trying with array_multisort with no luck.

```
        Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [taskuser] => Array
                            (
                                [profilepic] => 1e605ad76c82d41f6467c2525f796ebd.jpg
                                [postid] => 598
                                [message] => sweet!
                                  [created_time] => 2012-04-23 13:53:58
                            )

                        [time_created] => 3d
                        [likes] => Array
                            (
                                [like_type] => 0
                            )

                        [comments] => Array
                            (
                                [comments] => 0
                            )

                        [user_likes] => Array
                            (
                                [user_likes] => 0
                            )

                        [user_comments] => Array
                            (
                                [user_comments] => 0
                            )

                        [user_favorite] => Array
                            (
                                [isFav] => 0
                            )

                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [taskuser] => Array
                            (
                                [profilepic] => 1e605ad76c82d41f6467c2525f796ebd.jpg
                                [postid] => 598
                                [message] => sweet!
                                  [created_time] => 2012-04-23 14:05:20
                            )

                        [time_created] => 3d
                        [likes] => Array
                            (
                                [like_type] => 0
                            )

                        [comments] => Array
                            (
                                [comments] => 0
                            )

                        [user_likes] => Array
                            (
                                [user_likes] => 0
                            )

                        [user_comments] => Array
                            (
                                [user_comments] => 0
                            )

                        [user_favorite] => Array
                            (
                                [isFav] => 0
                            )

                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [taskuser] => Array
                            (
                                [profilepic] => 1e605ad76c82d41f6467c2525f796ebd.jpg
                                [postid] => 598
                                [message] => sweet!
                                  [created_time] => 2012-04-23 14:09:11
                            )

                        [time_created] => 3d
                        [likes] => Array
                            (
                                [like_type] => 0
                            )

                        [comments] => Array
                            (
                                [comments] => 0
                            )

                        [user_likes] => Array
                            (
                                [user_likes] => 0
                            )

                        [user_comments] => Array
                            (
                                [user_comments] => 0
                            )

                        [user_favorite] => Array
                            (
                                [isFav] => 0
                            )

                    )

                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [taskuser] => Array
                            (
                                [profilepic] => 1e605ad76c82d41f6467c2525f796ebd.jpg
                                [postid] => 598
                                [message] => sweet!
                                  [created_time] => 2012-04-23 14:11:35
                            )

                        [time_created] => 3d
                        [likes] => Array
                            (
                                [like_type] => 0
                            )

                        [comments] => Array
                            (
                                [comments] => 0
                            )

                        [user_likes] => Array
                            (
                                [user_likes] => 0
                            )

                        [user_comments] => Array
                            (
                                [user_comments] => 0
                            )

                        [user_favorite] => Array
                            (
                                [isFav] => 0
                            )

                    )

                [4] => Array
                    (
                        [taskuser] => Array
                            (
                                [profilepic] => 1e605ad76c82d41f6467c2525f796ebd.jpg
                                [postid] => 598
                                [message] => sweet!
                                  [created_time] => 2012-05-25 11:22:17
                            )

                        [time_created] => 3d
                        [likes] => Array
                            (
                                [like_type] => 3
                            )

                        [comments] => Array
                            (
                                [comments] => 1
                            )

                        [user_likes] => Array
                            (
                                [user_likes] => 0
                            )

                        [user_comments] => Array
                            (
                                [user_comments] => 0
                            )

                        [user_favorite] => Array
                            (
                                [isFav] => 0
                            )

                    )

                [5] => Array
                    (
                        [taskuser] => Array
                            (
                                [profilepic] => 1e605ad76c82d41f6467c2525f796ebd.jpg
                                [postid] => 598
                                [message] => sweet!
                                  [created_time] => 2012-04-17 15:56:00
                            )

                        [time_created] => 3d
                        [likes] => Array
                            (
                                [like_type] => 0
                            )

                        [comments] => Array
                            (
                                [comments] => 0
                            )

                        [user_likes] => Array
                            (
                                [user_likes] => 0
                            )

                        [user_comments] => Array
                            (
                                [user_comments] => 0
                            )

                        [user_favorite] => Array
                            (
                                [isFav] => 0
                            )

                    )

                [6] => Array
                    (
                        [taskuser] => Array
                            (
                                [profilepic] => 1e605ad76c82d41f6467c2525f796ebd.jpg
                                [postid] => 598
                                [message] => sweet!
                                  [created_time] => 2012-04-17 15:58:03
                            )

                        [time_created] => 3d
                        [likes] => Array
                            (
                                [like_type] => 0
                            )

                        [comments] => Array
                            (
                                [comments] => 0
                            )

                        [user_likes] => Array
                            (
                                [user_likes] => 0
                            )

                        [user_comments] => Array
                            (
                                [user_comments] => 0
                            )

                        [user_favorite] => Array
                            (
                                [isFav] => 0
                            )

                    )

                [7] => Array
                    (
                        [taskuser] => Array
                            (
                                [profilepic] => 1e605ad76c82d41f6467c2525f796ebd.jpg
                                [postid] => 598
                                [message] => sweet!
                                  [created_time] => 2012-04-20 16:24:53
                            )

                        [time_created] => 3d
                        [likes] => Array
                            (
                                [like_type] => 0
                            )

                        [comments] => Array
                            (
                                [comments] => 0
                            )

                        [user_likes] => Array
                            (
                                [user_likes] => 0
                            )

                        [user_comments] => Array
                            (
                                [user_comments] => 0
                            )

                        [user_favorite] => Array
                            (
                                [isFav] => 0
                            )

                    )

                [8] => Array
                    (
                        [taskuser] => Array
                            (
                                [profilepic] => 1e605ad76c82d41f6467c2525f796ebd.jpg
                                [postid] => 598
                                [message] => sweet!
                                  [created_time] => 2012-05-11 15:56:55
                            )

                        [time_created] => 3d
                        [likes] => Array
                            (
                                [like_type] => 1
                            )

                        [comments] => Array
                            (
                                [comments] => 0
                            )

                        [user_likes] => Array
                            (
                                [user_likes] => 0
                            )

                        [user_comments] => Array
                            (
                                [user_comments] => 0
                            )

                        [user_favorite] => Array
                            (
                                [isFav] => 0
                            )

                    )

                [9] => Array
                    (
                        [taskuser] => Array
                            (
                               [profilepic] => 1e605ad76c82d41f6467c2525f796ebd.jpg
                                [postid] => 598
                                [message] => sweet!
                                  [created_time] => 2012-05-11 16:05:35
                            )

                        [time_created] => 3d
                        [likes] => Array
                            (
                                [like_type] => 1
                            )

                        [comments] => Array
                            (
                                [comments] => 4
                            )

                        [user_likes] => Array
                            (
                                [user_likes] => 0
                            )

                        [user_comments] => Array
                            (
                                [user_comments] => 0
                            )

                        [user_favorite] => Array
                            (
                                [isFav] => 0
                            )

                    )

                [10] => Array
                    (
                        [taskuser] => Array
                            (
                               [profilepic] => 1e605ad76c82d41f6467c2525f796ebd.jpg
                                [postid] => 598
                                [message] => sweet!
                                  [created_time] => 2012-05-30 21:04:00
                            )

                        [time_created] => 3d
                        [likes] => Array
                            (
                                [like_type] => 0
                            )

                        [comments] => Array
                            (
                                [comments] => 0
                            )

                        [user_likes] => Array
                            (
                                [user_likes] => 0
                            )

                        [user_comments] => Array
                            (
                                [user_comments] => 0
                            )

                        [user_favorite] => Array
                            (
                                [isFav] => 0
                            )

                    )

                [11] => Array
                    (
                        [taskuser] => Array
                            (
                               [profilepic] => 1e605ad76c82d41f6467c2525f796ebd.jpg
                                [postid] => 598
                                [message] => sweet!
                                  [created_time] => 2012-05-30 21:04:55
                            )

                        [time_created] => 3d
                        [likes] => Array
                            (
                                [like_type] => 0
                            )

                        [comments] => Array
                            (
                                [comments] => 0
                            )

                        [user_likes] => Array
                            (
                                [user_likes] => 0
                            )

                        [user_comments] => Array
                            (
                                [user_comments] => 0
                            )

                        [user_favorite] => Array
                            (
                                [isFav] => 0
                            )

                    )

                [12] => Array
                    (
                        [taskuser] => Array
                            (
                                [profilepic] => 1e605ad76c82d41f6467c2525f796ebd.jpg
                                [postid] => 598
                                [message] => sweet!
                                  [created_time] => 2012-04-17 15:54:32
                            )

                        [time_created] => 3d
                        [likes] => Array
                            (
                                [like_type] => 0
                            )

                        [comments] => Array
                            (
                                [comments] => 0
                            )

                        [user_likes] => Array
                            (
                                [user_likes] => 0
                            )

                        [user_comments] => Array
                            (
                                [user_comments] => 0
                            )

                        [user_favorite] => Array
                            (
                                [isFav] => 0
                            )

                    )

                [13] => Array
                    (
                        [taskuser] => Array
                            (
                                [profilepic] => 1e605ad76c82d41f6467c2525f796ebd.jpg
                                [postid] => 598
                                [message] => sweet!
                                  [created_time] => 2012-04-17 15:54:54
                            )

                        [time_created] => 3d
                        [likes] => Array
                            (
                                [like_type] => 0
                            )

                        [comments] => Array
                            (
                                [comments] => 0
                            )

                        [user_likes] => Array
                            (
                                [user_likes] => 0
                            )

                        [user_comments] => Array
                            (
                                [user_comments] => 0
                            )

                        [user_favorite] => Array
                            (
                                [isFav] => 0
                            )

                    )

                [14] => Array
                    (
                        [taskuser] => Array
                            (
                                [profilepic] => 1e605ad76c82d41f6467c2525f796ebd.jpg
                                [postid] => 598
                                [message] => sweet!
                                  [created_time] => 2012-04-17 15:53:19
                            )

                        [time_created] => 3d
                        [likes] => Array
                            (
                                [like_type] => 0
                            )

                        [comments] => Array
                            (
                                [comments] => 1
                            )

                        [user_likes] => Array
                            (
                                [user_likes] => 0
                            )

                        [user_comments] => Array
                            (
                                [user_comments] => 0
                            )

                        [user_favorite] => Array
                            (
                                [isFav] => 0
                            )

                    )

            )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where $results is the array above, try

```
usort($results, function($a, $b){
    //check case for same number of user likes
    if ($a['user_likes']['user_likes'] == $b['user_likes']['user_likes']){
        if (strtotime($a['taskuser']['created_time']) == strtotime($b['taskuser']['created_time'])){
            return 0;
        } else if (strtotime($a['taskuser']['created_time']) < strtotime($b['taskuser']['created_time'])){
            return 1;
        } else {
            return -1;
        }

    } else if ($a['user_likes']['user_likes'] < $b['user_likes']['user_likes']){
        return 1;
    } else {
        return -1;  
    }
});
```

Comment: This assumes you are using PHP 5.3 since it is using a closure for the callback.

Answer (score 1):

You want [`usort`](http://php.net/usort). Have the callback compare the `user_likes`, then the `created_time`.